# Getting an error while importing tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-import, importerror

```py
    Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py:58
    56   sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
    --->58 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    59 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__
```

I tried importing tensorflow and keras but i'm getting some error. This never happened before but suddenly i get this error`your text`

Comment: "Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor" You should do this, and post the full traceback here.

Comment: What is the exact code you are using which shows this error? Also please let us know about the installed TensorFlow version, Platform detail(Jupyter, Google Colab, Pycharm etc.) along with the system OS details where you are facing this issue.